# Cannot find module ' ./' in Node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to test a module called mfcc for Node js. However, when I run a command **node mfcc.js**, I get the following error: *Cannot find module ' ./' in Node js*

Comment: did you set `NODE_PATH`? If not, just run: `export NODE_PATH=\`pwd\``

Comment: It's a publicaly avaliable modul called mfcc. In the code there is a following line : mfcc = require('./');. But what does that mean?

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: `require('./')` would look for an `index` or `index.js` file in the current directory.

Comment: @BenFortune Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. For some reason then I installed the module using **npm install mfcc** it didn't download index.js to the mfcc folder located in node_modules folder. Then I manually downloaded index.js from github version of mfcc, and it's now working.